# 3Sum Problem in Python 3, Time Limit Exceeded in Leetcode

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, big-o

I tried solving the 3Sum problem on Leetcode in python 3 but it shows that the time limit has exceeded for my solution.
3Sum problem is as follows:
Given array nums of n integers, are there elements a, b, c in nums such that a + b + c = 0? Find all unique triplets in the array which gives the sum of zero.

Note:

The solution set must not contain duplicate triplets.

Example:

Given array nums = [-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4],

A solution set is:

[-1, 0, 1], [-1, -1, 2].
I have been trying to figure it for a long time but in vain. Also, I am new to this so please bear with me.

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]
        res =[]
        size = len(nums)
        nums.sort()
        for i in range(size-2):
         
            if i> 0 and nums[i] == nums[i-1]:
                continue

            low = i+1
            high = size - 1

            while(low<high):
                val = nums[low]+nums[high] + nums[i]
                if(val < 0)  or ((low < high) and nums[low] == nums[low+1]):

                    low = low + 1
                elif( val > 0) or ((low < high) and nums[high] == nums[high-1]):

                    high = high - 1
                else:
                    res.append( (nums[i], nums[low], nums[high]))
        return(res)
```

Can someone please tell me what's the mistake.

Comment: I have updated my post with the questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do that O(N ^ 2). O(N ^ 3) is not acceptable:

```
from typing import List

class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        unique_triplets = []
        nums.sort()
        for i in range(len(nums) - 2):
            if i > 0 and nums[i] == nums[i - 1]:
                continue
            lo = i + 1
            hi = len(nums) - 1
            while lo < hi:
                target_sum = nums[i] + nums[lo] + nums[hi]
                if target_sum < 0:
                    lo += 1
                if target_sum > 0:
                    hi -= 1
                if target_sum == 0:
                    unique_triplets.append((nums[i], nums[lo], nums[hi]))
                    while lo < hi and nums[lo] == nums[lo + 1]:
                        lo += 1
                    while lo < hi and nums[hi] == nums[hi - 1]:
                        hi -= 1
                    lo += 1
                    hi -= 1
        return unique_triplets
```

#### One of LeetCode's solution:

```
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        res = []
        found, dups = set(), set()
        seen = {}
        for i, val1 in enumerate(nums):
            if val1 not in dups:
                dups.add(val1)
                for j, val2 in enumerate(nums[i+1:]):
                    complement = -val1 - val2
                    if complement in seen and seen[complement] == i:
                        min_val = min((val1, val2, complement))
                        max_val = max((val1, val2, complement))
                        if (min_val, max_val) not in found:
                            found.add((min_val, max_val))
                            res.append([val1, val2, complement])
                    seen[val2] = i
        return res
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions, explanations, efficient algorithms with a variety of languages, and time/space complexity analysis in there.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop runs forever if it ever finds a result to put into the results list. That's because the `else` clause inside your `while` loop doesn't do anything to change the loop condition, so it will just keep running with the same `low`, `high` and `i` values until you run out of memory to store them.

I suspect you want to advance both `low` and `high` after appending a solution to the results:

```
        while(low<high):
            val = nums[low]+nums[high] + nums[i]
            if(val < 0)  or ((low < high) and nums[low] == nums[low+1]):

                low = low + 1
            elif( val > 0) or ((low < high) and nums[high] == nums[high-1]):

                high = high - 1
            else:
                res.append( (nums[i], nums[low], nums[high]))
                low = low + 1
                high = high - 1
```